# Ruby String Split on "\t" loses "\n"

Tags: arrays, ruby, split

\tTrying to split this Tab delimited data set:

```
171 1000    21  
269 1000    25  
389 1000    40  
1020    1-03    30  1
1058    1-03    30  1
1074    1-03    30  1
200 300     500
```

(for clarity: )

```
171\t1000\t21\t\n   
269\t1000\t25\t\n   
389\t1000\t40\t\n
1020\t1-03\t30\t1\n
1058\t1-03\t30\t1\n
1074\t1-03\t30\t1\n
200\t300\t\t500\n

a = text.split(/\n/)
a.each do |i|
  u = i.split(/\t/)
  puts u.size
end

==>
3
3
3
4
4
4
4
```

The \t\n combination seems to shave off the last \t, which I need for further importation.  How can I get around this?  Cheers

Edited: This is what I was expecting:

```
4
4
4
4
4
4
4
```

Comment: What is the output you were expecting? This seems to run as one would expect.

Comment: You should try CSV module with custom delimiters. CSV.read("path-to-file.csv", col_sep: "\t")

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding the question. You say "Trying to split this Tab delimited data set", but you don't say what you are splitting on. Also, I can't reconcile "The `\t\n` combination seems to shave off the last `\t`,..." with the title: "...split on `"\t"` loses `"\n"`. Do you first want to split on newlines, then split each of those strings on tabs, with the resulting arrays for the first three lines ending with an empty string? It would be particularly helpful if you could edit the question to show your desired result.

Comment: Also, I noticed that each of the first three lines contains one or more spaces between the last tab and the newline. Is that intentional? If so, do you want to keep those spaces?

Comment: The first three entries, a \t\n is significant and should import as a nil inside the record's array, not a 3-member array.

Comment: Could you please edit to show the desired result for your example?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If this is for production, you should be using the [CSV class](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.3/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html) as @DmitryZ pointed out in the comments. CSV processing has a surprising number of caveats and you should not do it by hand.

But let's go through it as an exercise...

---

The problem is split does not keep the delimiter, and it does not keep trailing null columns. You've hit both issues.

When you run `a = text.split(/\n/)` then the elements of `a` do not have newlines.

```
a = [
    171\t1000\t21\t   
    269\t1000\t25\t   
    389\t1000\t40\t
    1020\t1-03\t30\t1
    1058\t1-03\t30\t1
    1074\t1-03\t30\t1
    200\t300\t\t500
]
```

Then, [as documented in String#split](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.3/String.html#method-i-split), "*if the limit parameter is omitted, trailing null fields are suppressed.*", so `u = i.split(/\t/)` will ignore that last field ***unless*** you give it a limit.

If you know it's always going to be 4 fields, you can use 4.

```
u = i.split(/\t/, 4)
```

But it's probably more flexible to use -1 because "*If [the limit is] negative, there is no limit to the number of fields returned, and trailing null fields are not suppressed.*" so that will keep the empty fields without hard coding the number of columns in the CSV.

```
u = i.split(/\t/, -1)
```

Comment: I'm splitting using /\n/ first.  The issue shows up on each of those.  That limit seems to be the trick I was looking for.  Negative limit expands all apparent items.